# Finding difference in levels of a factor

Tags: r, date, difftime

I have %Y-%m formatted as a factor, with 24 levels. The data is formatted by aggregated activity within the months.

```
MemberID   Month_Yr   freq
1          2010-01     3
1          2010-03     6
2          2010-01     1
2          2010-05     2
3          2011-03     4 
4          2010-02     1
```

I am looking to compute the total number of months the customers have been active, by computing the difference between the oldest and newest active date.

Now, I've tried :

```
month.aggregated$MonthlyAverage <- ave(month.aggregated$freq, month.aggregated$ï..MemberID)
```

which doesn't return the correct value as there are some months that the customer isn't active. I somehow need the total number of levels to be included in the code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of months from the factor level like this:

```r
n_months <- 12 * as.numeric(substr(Month_Yr, 1, 4)) + as.numeric(Month_Yr, 6, 7))
```

So that you can then calculate months since records began like this:

```
df$month_count <- n_months - min(n_months)
```

and you can use dplyr to get the summary difference:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(MemberID) %>% summarize(months_active = max(month_count) - min(month_count))
```

Comment: I see what you do with the first 2 lines of code, but the third one doesn't do exactly what I need it to do. I'm looking to create a new column where each row is the length of contract to date for each member ID.  I want to use the total months in order to again calculate the average activity level within the months. As of now it only calculated the months that they have been active, but ignore the months were there are no values.

Comment: @amandr In that case, try `df %>% group_by(MemberID) %>% mutate(month_count = month_count - min(month_count))`